# Looking for R package or other possibility in R for General Bayesian Network Classification

Tags: r, classification, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

Hello stackoverflow community,

Im working on a uni-project in which we try to create Bayesian Network Classifier from data in R.
Ideally the classifier should be based on a General Bayesian Network (GNB) or a BN Augmented Naive Bayes(BAN).
Unfortunately Im yet to find a suitabel package to create either of those nets in R.
My research led me to the following two packages:

1. bnclassify, the most prominent package for BN classification, doesnt include GNBs or BANs at all.
2. bnlearn offers the possibility to learn GNBs but according to the creator the learning is focused on returning the correct dependence structure rather than  maximizing the predictive accuracy for classification. I've tried to use them for my classification problem nonetheless but the result was underwhelming.

So my question is if anyone knows a R package to classify with GNBs or BANs
OR how to work with the GNBs fron bnlearn to improve their predictive accuracy for classification problems.

Thanks you for your help in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: [`bnlearn`](https://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/naive.bayes.html) has naive Bayes and TAN classifiers

Comment: @user20650 Thank you for your replay. I know that! So does the bnclassify package. unfortunately im looking for a classifier based on GNBs oder BANs. Thanks

Comment: fair enough, I actually hadn't heard of BAN models. First web hit gave [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6684)  review paper. I'd think the BAN structure on page 104 could be leaned using bnlearn by adding / constraining edges using the whitelist / blacklist notation.

Comment: That's a paper I also found conducting my research. It indicates that the classifiers based on arbitrary graphs are somewhat superior to Tans and NB regarding classification accuracy. It also gives a step by step instruction on how to build the different types of Bayes classifiers so I was hoping to find a package that could perfom the described steps e.g. CBLl algorithm which is used for BANs or GNBs.